# Random sorting bits in matrix

Tags: matlab

Could you help me. I have matrix but I want to have more "fixed_part" in matrix and to be randomly selected. Also is important that every row be unique. Could you help me?

```
clear all
clc
ntags = 50;
fixed_part = 20;
IDlength = 64;




tag_population = [zeros(ntags, fixed_part), floor(rand(ntags,IDlength-fixed_part)*2)];   
tag_population = unique(tag_population,'rows');
```

Look this matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

In this example I have four different type of "fixed_part".

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "more fixed_part"? Higher values?

Comment: @hbaderts, ''fixed_part'' presents how many '0' are between group of '0 and 1' randomy sorted. I want more 'fixed_part' in matrix

Comment: I might still understand you wrong (sorry if that's the case), but can't you just set `fixed_part` to a higher number, e.g. 30, to get that?

Comment: @hbaderts, Yes but again I will have matrix with just one "fixed_part".

Comment: "More fixed part" sounds very SNL. :-)

Comment: Ah, so you want something like `[fixed_part   random_parts   fixed_part   other_random_parts]`?

Comment: @hbaderts, Looks my example above

Comment: I am unable to understand the question, I don't know what you want to increase.

Comment: It might help if you provide an example of your desired output and explain how it differs from your current output.

Comment: Could you see that first 3 rows has the same number of '0' before first 1. The same manner is fit next  2 rows, and so on... I want to radomly change this number of '0' before first '1'

Comment: if you just want to randomly change the number of '0' before first '1' you can use `circshift` which shifts your row by x units towards a direction (use 'post' or 'pre') the x units can be generated by a random number between 1 and the length of your row. - I still do not understand the question...

Comment: @GameOfThrows, could you type me code of this from example? Because it is not my output.

Comment: `Y = circshift(YourMatrix(1,:),randi([1 size(YourMatrix,1)],1,1))`

Comment: @GameOfThrows, no you don't understand me :( I want new matrix in which  looks on this example above. You gave me just one row. 
Do  you see that first three rows in example that have same number before first 1. Also after that 4th and 5th rows has another number of '0' before first 1 and so on in  following rows. I want this from example

Comment: I gave you the code for 1 row, you can just iterate it for the number of rows in your code. I am sorry, but it is hard to understand.

Comment: @NikolaC Your question does not specify what you actually want. I'm voting to close until you can clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer with the full matrix you wanted:

```
for t =  1:size(A,1)
   Y(t,:) = circshift(A(t,:)',randi([1 size(A,2)],1,1)')

%//EDIT added first 4 digits cannot be 0
   while sum(Y(t,1:4) > 0) 
   Y(t,:) = circshift(A(t,:)',2)
   end

%//Be warned, can run into infinite loop if the first 4 digits must contains at least a 1.

end
```

where A is your input matrix.

Y =

```
 0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Already an increase in "More fix part" right?

Comment: It is good but I should not have 1 on first four positions.

Comment: @NikolaC I edited my answer to incorporate the change

Comment: it is unceasing path. Ii is not work